# Cross domain Json data using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am getting data in browser (in json format) but I am unable to get data in Javascript code. Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://reelcinemas.ae/Data/MoviesSession.json?callback=?",
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (nowShowing) {
                nowShowingMoviesData = nowShowing;
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) { alert(error.text); },

        });
});
```

I see error in browser console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

If I change code :

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://reelcinemas.ae/Data/MoviesSession.json?jsonCallback=?",
            processData: true,
            data: {},
            dataType: 'text/xml',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            success: function (data) {
                processData(data);
            }
        });
        function jsonCallback(data) {
            console.log(data);

        }
```

I get error:  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:51418' is therefore not allowed access.

But I can access the data from browser.

thanks

Comment: change `dataType: 'jsonp'` to `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: So the server isn't returning jsonp but json

Comment: Is the data you're getting back valid `jsonp`?

Comment: first, are you sure the server can generate a `JSONP` output? also, you don't need any sort of `?jsonCallback=?`, jQuery does that for you.

Comment: @vsync As i can test it checking URL, it isn't

Comment: That means server owner doesn't allow any external website to embed his own data. A workaround would be to reserver it using your server but don't, this is like stealing other people data. And FYI, jsonp request cannot be sync

Answer (score 0):

**[CORS – Cross Origin Resource Sharing.](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)**

You need your server to allow clients to load resources if they have a different origin (on a different server).

This means, if `reelcinemas.ae` does not send the mentioned header (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) your client will not load resources from there.

For example, an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: */*` header would allow all clients to load data from there via AJAX.

**EDIT 1**

To get around this limitation you can create for example a PHP script on your page with this content and call it form your script:

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("http://reelcinemas.ae/Data/MoviesSession.json");
?>
```

Read [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) for even more details.

If the API provider `reelcinemas.ae` does not send such a header, they don't want you to load this resource via AJAX.